# Processing Background Tasks on a Scheduled Basis While returning HTTP Requests

Tags: python, django, background-task

**Here is what I am trying to accomplish:**

1. GET Request is made
2. Background task is scheduled. Response that task has been scheduled is made.
3. After ten seconds (after the response has been made), the task is processed.

I want to do this asynchronously so that the computer that made the call is not waiting on the response and can perform other tasks without wasting CPU.

I am able to process the background tasks if I use the command

```
python manage.py process_tasks
```

but I want this to occur automatically on a routine basis in my Python code.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing background tasks was the wrong way to solve my problem, but I have the solution for processing background tasks via python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("python manage.py process_tasks")
```